# how to block an email sent using a script in EXIM

Tags: exim

I have a CentOS cPanel server and I host about 30 customers in this server.

Sometimes one of these accounts using a CMS get hacked, and the hacker is able to send out spam email using a CMS php vulnerability.

When it happens I see hundred of rows like this below in EXIM log:

```
2019-07-29 06:40:30 cwd=/home/nordic/public_html 4 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -p125
```

My question is, may I configure temporarily `exim.conf` to block any email sent from:

```
/home/nordic/public_html
```

If yes, how to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that exim (as `/usr/bin/sendmail`) can see $CWD

but that doesn't mean that you cannot replace `/usr/bin/sendmail` with a script of your own that makes these sort of checks before invoking `/usr/sbin/exim`

eg:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f  email_blocked.flag ] 
then exit 1
fi
exec /usr/sbin/exim "$@"
```

this script checks for existance of a file email_blocked.flag in the current directory and refuses to send if it is found.

This won't block anyone smart enough to call /usr/sbin/exim directly, but even disabling exim fully won't prevent them using phpmailer.